# Overlapping counter textview on image in relativelayout or linearlayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I want to place a textview on top right corner of imageview and also to overlap some part of textview on to imageview. How can i do that. Right now I am doing this:

```
     <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dip"
                >


                <ImageView 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imgMessage"
                    android:src="@drawable/listing_message"
                    />



                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/tvMessageCounter"
                    android:layout_width="20dip"
                    android:layout_height="20dip"
                    android:padding="2dip"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/whiteColor"
                    android:background="@layout/bg_blue"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgMessage"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Show some picture how it should be.

Comment: try using framelayout

Comment: Please show your snapshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overlap textview on image view in XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42668906/how-to-overlap-textview-on-image-view-in-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need overlapping you should use the FrameLayout.

```
<FrameLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dip"
            >


            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imgMessage"
                android:src="@drawable/listing_message"
                />



            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tvMessageCounter"
                android:layout_width="20dip"
                android:layout_height="20dip"
                android:padding="2dip"
                android:marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="@drawable/whiteColor"
                android:background="@layout/bg_blue"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                />

        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: can you help me achieve the design as shown in attached image via framelayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/imgMessage"
      android:src="@drawable/listing_message"
      />
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/tvMessageCounter"
 android:layout_width="20dip"
 android:layout_height="20dip"
android:gravity="bottom|right"



</FrameLayout>
```

Based on design you can give padding and margin required.

Answer (score 0):

You did right but the only thing needed is to swap your views

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessageCounter"
        android:layout_width="20dip"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgMessage"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@layout/bg_blue"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:text="20"
        android:textColor="@drawable/whiteColor"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/listing_message" />

</RelativeLayout>
```