# How to overlap textview on image view in XML?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have two images in android where one is image and another one is `drawable` which show the numbering here. please let me know how could be possible to overlap both these things.[image]

**here my code:**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/catfish_img"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_cat_fish" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/circle_tv"
    android:layout_below="@+id/video_chat_txt"
    android:text="2"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"/>
```

Comment: use relativelayout and then set ImageView and TextView in it according to your requirement

Comment: @ZakiPathan    it's already in relative layout

Comment: use android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" in TextView

Comment: you need to give static size of imageview also for possible to this view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code and You have to use third library for circular text view.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/catfish_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/intro1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/circle_tv"
        android:text="2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"

        />
    <!--android:background="@drawable/circle"-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Use these libraries for badge icon
http://www.exceptionbound.com/programming-tut/android-tutorial/add-badge-item-count-to-icon-android-app-android-studio

https://github.com/arturogutierrez/Badges

https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-ActionItemBadge

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

**Output** will be like this

[image]

Comment: yes!! but is there any way where i can get my textview on image? if it's possible please tell me. thanks

Comment: Please tell me how https://github.com/arturogutierrez/Badges will work?

Comment: @TavinderSingh. Your welcome, Please subscribe my youtube channel for more  updates https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCA5HRmlkT7bqbO56EIlT0UQ

Answer (score 0):

Place both in a relative layout and then align the text as necessary within the relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/catfish_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_cat_fish" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/circle_tv"
            android:layout_below="@+id/video_chat_txt"
            android:text="2"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```